# trying to consume wcf service but I think my web.config file is incorrect

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-client

I am having try trying to consume a service. I am trying to deploy it to a server and consume it however I get this error. I have created a web application and added a wcf service. I am getting this

> Server stack trace: 
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at IBusinessV1.CheckForUpdate(String currentVersion)
>      at BusinessV1Client.CheckForUpdate(String currentVersion)

Is there something wrong with my config?

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <services>
      <service name="SP.WebWCF.Business_v1">
          <endpoint 
             address="https://services.mydomain.com" 
             binding="basicHttpBinding"
             bindingConfiguration="" 
             contract="SP.WebWCF.IBusiness_v1"
             listenUri="/" isSystemEndpoint="true" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
       <serviceBehaviors>
           <behavior>
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
           </behavior>
       </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Where is this service hosted: IIS or self hosted?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your did show the server config, but you never really told us what the error is - you show the stack trace - but not the error message.....

Anyway, looking at your service config, one thing seems a bit odd - your service address:

```
address="https://services.mydomain.com" 
binding="basicHttpBinding"
```

Typically this would either be something like

```
address="https://services.mydomain.com/MyServiceVirtualDir/MyService.svc"
```

if you're hosting your service inside IIS, or something like

```
address="https://services.mydomain.com/MyService"
```

if you're self-hosting in a Windows NT service or something.

Can you double-check your address - are you 100% sure it's correct??

**Update:** also, you're using **`https://`**, however, you're not showing any security-settings in your service config. Just for test: can you invoke your service when you change the service address in the config to just `http://` ??

Comment: Sorry this is my service. I am trying to consume the service using the WCF Test Client but get the above error

Comment: @user293545: unfortunately, you never gave us the error - the actual message you're getting - only the stack trace......

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information. I am hosting the service in IIS 7 in the root of my site. so should the service endpoint look like "endpoint address="https://services.mydomain.com/Business_V1.svc" ? As this doesnt work. I get this error Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

Comment: Yes my service address is correct if I add it into the browser I am ale to access the wsdl

Comment: @user293545: yes, if you're hosting in IIS7, and you're using basicHttpBinding, you typically need a *.svc file - **unless** you're using .NET 4 and file-less activation - again, you didn't specify.....

Comment: @user293545: you say: *the browser I am able to access the wsdl* - what URL (exactly!) are you using?? http:// or https:// ? With or without *.svc file ??